# I am trying to limit input characters in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am aware of the possibility to limit amount of characters in google sheets cell to have a message or color show up.

Im trying to figure out if it is possible to limit the characters by simply not having the possibility put more characters in. after (for example) 25 characters it just stops writing or it doesn't save the file or something similar...

thnx for the help,

Marty

Comment: can you add a screenshot for more clarity? Do you not want to allow user to enter more than 25 characters in a particular cell?

Comment: Try to use validation

Answer (score 0):

### You can do it with an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

- an [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger would allow you to retrieve on each edit the value of the edited cell with the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e.range`
- subsequently, you can use [str.length](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) to verify either the entered value has more than the allowed number of characters
- if the latter is the case, you can retrieve the edited range with `e.range` and [set its value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) back to an empty string `""`
- additionally, you can implement an [alert](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt) that asks the user to input a shorter value

Sample script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var value = e.value;
  if (value.length > 25){
    var range = e.range;
    range.setValue("");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The allowed input is max. 25 characters")
  }
}
```

[Bind](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) this script to your spreadsheet, save it and test it by inputting a value longer than 25 characters in any cell of the spreadsheet. I encourage you to study the Apps Script documentation to learn how to modify the script and adapt to your needs.